# Join 2 Dataframes with Regex in where clause pyspark

Tags: regex, dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark

We have two dataframes

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
        (1, 'Nick', 'Miller'),
        (2, 'Jessica', 'Day'),
        (3, 'Winston', 'Schmidt'),
       ], ['id', 'First_name', 'Last_name'])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([ (1, '^[a-lA-L]', 'type1'), (3, '^[m-zM-Z]', 'type2')], ['id', 'regex_match', 'vaule']
```

Need to join these two dataframe, where `df1.regex_match` matches with `df.Last_name`

Needed output be like following: Any suggestion please:

[image: OutPut Dataframe be like]

```
join df to df1 using left join
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join using an `rlike` condition:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.alias('df').join(
    df1.drop('id').alias('df1'),
    F.expr('df.Last_name rlike df1.regex_match'),
    'left'
).drop('regex_match')

result.show()
+---+----------+---------+-----+
| id|First_name|Last_name|vaule|
+---+----------+---------+-----+
|  1|      Nick|   Miller|type2|
|  2|   Jessica|      Day|type1|
|  3|   Winston|  Schmidt|type2|
+---+----------+---------+-----+
```